# Turning off execution of custom query in looker studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have googled and I don't seem to figure out how to do this.
Does anyone know how to turn off the refreshing of a custom query from bigquery, that is directly connected in looker studio. I would use connected sheets and then add it from google spread sheets, but it has too many rows so I can't do it that way.

I want to avoid unnecessary scan costs and the data I have does not need to be updated often that why I am asking this.

Can I turn off the refreshing/execution of my query from my looker studio report? Or would it be enough to make my query a scheduled query in bigquery and set the execution to manual?

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referring to [data freshness](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020039?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) ?  It appears that you cannot disable this as you can only set it on interval values.

> **Set data freshness for a data source**
> Looker Studio automatically refreshes all the cached data for each data source used by your report at certain intervals. 
> To change the default data refresh rate:
>
> - Edit the data source. You can do this from within a report, or from the Data Sources home page.
> - At the top, click Data freshness.
> - Under "Check for fresh data," select a new refresh option, if available.
>   Click SET DATA FRESHNESS.

If this is the case your workaround about scheduled query and running it manually is possibly viable for the use case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I think that is what I am referring too. Unfortunately I could not find anything less frequent than 12 hours in the settings for the data source. If there is a way to not run the query even if it refreshes the source, then I am fine with it being 12 hours. Otherwise I have to keep searching for other ways to solve this problem.